# File did not find error in CSS, but background image is not displaying

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have created an external stylesheet named `new.css`. It is linked in `new.html`, but the problem is, the image is not displaying. I have put all my three files `new.html`, `new.css`, and `banner_bg.png` in the same mobile assets folder.

I'm new in Cascading Style Sheets, so please guys help me out how to do this. Thank you.

[Here's my code in JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/archan/v11ambba/2/)

Comment: show the html tag

Comment: or correct .PNG or .png in html tag

Comment: i have done that but still same error :( https://jsfiddle.net/archan/v11ambba/2/

Comment: The code that you posted on jsfiddle contains an absolute path, put a relative path in the background image.

Comment: It depends on what you want it to look like, but you probably don't need the position absolute so remove that, you don't need to show absolute paths to your image, as you say they're all in the same folder, you could just have `background-image:url("banner_bg.png");` and you need to define some dimensions to the div you're applying it to like `height:300px;` because with nothing in it, the div will collapse to no height

Comment: i knew it, now you have your answers good luck

Comment: make sure, your image lies in the same directory of html n css file

Comment: yes i have confirmed that it is in same folder.

Comment: @PhilS i have tried but not working that

Comment: where is your html & css file located?
Check that you have given the correct path of css and it is loaded in browser. You can check in Inspect Element > Network Tab

Comment: banner_bg.png => banner_bg.PNG replace this

Comment: Thanks a lot guys it worked but now the problem is if i define the height it does not display whole image.https://jsfiddle.net/archan/v11ambba/7/ @PhilS

Comment: help me guys now i'm so close

Answer (score 1):

You have absolute path for the image in the CSS.

Use relative path instead:

```
background-image: url("banner_bg.png");
```

Your div is absolutely positioned and has no content in it, which means its dimensions are `0x0`. You will need to add some height and width (you might want to add them in `%`).

```
height: 200px;
width: 700px;
```

---

If for some reason you want to use the absolute path, you would do it like this (**not recommended**, as it will work for you, but nobody else):

```
background-image: url("file:///E:/Assignment Work/SWP/Assets/mobile assets/banner_bg.png");
```

Comment: yeah i have tried both the way but still it showing blank page no background image appearing

Comment: @Arch8 this should be working if you have html, css, img file in same folder.

Comment: Does that div have any height and width, or some content in it? Try adding some text.

Comment: no it does not have any height can you give me e.g i have done that but it get wrong.

Comment: The div is also absolutely positioned without any content in it. You will need to add width as well. https://jsfiddle.net/v11ambba/6/

Comment: try using background-image:url("/mobile assets/banner_bg.png")
" / " at start it points to root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

> position: absolute

and specify some height to check (as @pol suggested)

```
.top
{
 height: 500px;
 background-image:url("https://www.hello.com/img_/hello_logo_hero.png");    // Change with this your RELATIVE path
}
```

Comment: that's working fine but i want image from my local drive

Comment: thats an easy fix, just change the path to be to a file in your filesystem. background-image: url("banner_bg.png");

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.top
{
  background-image:url("https://cdn3.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2015/04/usertesting.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  display:block;
}
```